# Protractor Not able to click the element While iterating the list of Elements

Tags: typescript, protractor

clickClaimIDFromList(claimId) {

```
   element.all(by.xpath('//*[@data-qa="dashboard.claim"]')).then(async (items) => {
            // console.log(items[0].getText());
            await expect(items[0].getText()).to.eventually.equal('12345');

            items.forEach(item => {
                     item.getText().then(async (text) => {
                            if (text === '12345') {
                                await console.log(item.getText());
                                await this.wait(10000);
                                return item.click();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }


     );

}
```

This code is getting executed successfully with out clicking the element. Could some one help me to rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `async/await` keywords I am assuming your have the control flow disabled in your framework (by setting `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in conf.js).

If that is the case there is no need to be using so many `.then`'s as `await` provides a much easier way to handle them.

Your test could be passing because it is hitting the failing the `text === '12345'` check in your if and therefore never attempting to click.

```
//Make function async
async clickClaimIDFromList(claimId) {

  let allElems = await element.all(by.xpath('//*[@data-qa="dashboard.claim"]'));

  //don't await expects, await what is occuring inside them if you need to
  expect(await allElems[0].getText()).to.eventually.equal('12345');

  for (let i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
    let item = allElems[i];

    //Save the result of the getText to a variable
    let itemText = await item.getText();
    console.log(itemText);

    if (itemText === '12345') {
      await this.wait(10000);

      //No need to return the click, we can await it here
      await item.click();
    } else {
      console.log('else is being hit');
  }
}
```

Note: I have not tested this code but the logic should be correct

Comment: Glad to hear it, would you mind accepting this answer in case others find the question also

Answer (score 0):

Executable code:

async clickClaimIDFromList() {

```
    const allElems = await element.all(by.xpath('//*[@data-qa="dashboard.claim"]'));


    for (let i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
        const item = allElems[i];

        // Save the result of the getText to a variable
        const itemText = await item.getText();
        console.log(itemText);

        if (itemText === '123124214') {
            await this.wait(10000);

            // No need to return the click, we can await it here
            await item.click();
        } else {
            console.log('else is being hit');
        }

    }
}
```